# TI ARM with stacked RAM

Tags: arm, robotics, texas-instruments, omap

Do any of the TI ARM SOCs, e.g. OMAP or Da Vinci, have a version with stacked RAM? (e.g. DDR2 or mDDR) For miniature robots, it would be really nice to not need to spend board area on an external RAM chip. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the TI web site?

Comment: Yes, but the TI site contradicts Wikipedia - wikipedia mentions a bunch of OMAPs with stacked RAM, but TI does not appear to have them listed anymore except on an old part of the site with broken HTML.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMAP#Basic_multimedia_applications_processors

Comment: http://www.ti.com/general/docs/wtbu/wtbuproductcontent.tsp?templateId=6123&navigationId=12801&contentId=41248

Comment: Check the 2009 press release for the OMAP-DM5x for example at http://www.reuters.com/article/2009/10/06/idUS117199+06-Oct-2009+PRN20091006 and look at the "availability" section. The problem using Wikipedia for those sorts of things is the editor probably used something like that as a citation, and being an OEM-only product there's probably never been a public EOL notice. Even if there was it doesn't mean anyone would notice and go back to update the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: NO. All news microprocessors from TI don't have stacked memory.